# SQLite Insertion not writing to database - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm new to using SQLite and Objective-C. Below is my code for writing a photo ("moment") to a database.

```
-(void) sendMoment: (Album *) alb moment:(Moment *) m
{
    @try {
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        // First, test for existence of writable file:
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photos.sqlite"];
        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
        if (!success){
            // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
            NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photos.sqlite"];
            success = [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
            if (!success) {
                NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }

        //add passed-in moment to the given album
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        NSData *dataFromArray = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:m.moment];
        NSString *momentInsertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO MomentTbl (momentID, albumID, title, timestamp, author, latitude, longitude, canvas) VALUES (NULL, %d, '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@')", alb.ID, alb.title, m.timestamp, @"user", m.latitude, m.longitude, dataFromArray];

        const char *query_stmt = [momentInsertSQL UTF8String];
        const char *dbPath = [writableDBPath UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                    NSLog(@"OK");
                else
                    NSLog(@"Problem");


                sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
                sqlite3_close(db);
            }
        }    
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
    }
}
```

The code compiles, but when I take a picture and call `sendMoment`, nothing seems to be written to the database.  As far as I know, the code should ensure that the phone has access to the database in the first part. The `sqlite3_prepare_v2` statement returns 0. Also, the `sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);` returns 0 - after doing some research, I'm still not sure what that means, or if it's significant. I think that the problem lies either in the formatting of the INSERT itself or in the if statements below it, but I really can't say for sure. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: What debugging have you done? How far does this code get? Where does it fail? Why aren't you properly logging errors or properly closing the database? Why do you prepare the statement twice?

Comment: Yes, preparing the statement twice could do lots of odd things.  Also, print out your writeableDBPath, open a Mac command window, navigate to that directory, and use `sqlite3` to check the DB.

Comment: I edited the code to only use the prepare_v2 statement, but that didn't fix it. The DB is on the iPhone that I'm simulating on, I'm not sure how to check the DB on it.

Comment: Also, you should not be embedding your data into your SQL statement but instead should use sqlite3_bind_xx calls, especially for the dataFromArray (which should be handled as a blob).  And you should not open/close the DB for every operation -- open it once and leave it open until the app ends or until you're done with the DB.

Comment: You can use -- oh, what is it? the service that starts with an O in the Xcode Windows tab -- Organizer?? -- to download files from an attached phone.  (But you're better off doing your initial DB debugging on the simulator.)

Comment: (Hint: NSLog your momentInsertSQL statement -- it's gonna look pretty weird.)